# Force Proguard to give every method in a class a unique name?

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I'm using Proguard to obfuscate an Android application. Everything works fine but I'm struggling to retrace stack traces from error reports.

Here's an extract of my obfuscated code:

```
    private ez a(x paramx)
  {
    return (ez)this.J.get(paramx);
  }

  private void a(com.b.a.f paramf)
  {
    Iterator localIterator = this.K.iterator();
    while (true)
    {
      if (!localIterator.hasNext())
        return;
      em localem = (em)localIterator.next();
      if (localem.a((int)(this.i / this.m - 202.0F), (int)(202.0F + (this.i + this.n) / this.m), (int)(this.j / this.m - 202.0F), (int)(202.0F + (this.j + this.o) / this.m)))
        localem.a(paramf, this.m, this.i, this.j);
    }
  }

  private void a(com.b.a.f paramf, int paramInt1, int paramInt2, int paramInt3, int paramInt4)
  {
    Iterator localIterator = this.J.entrySet().iterator();
    while (true)
    {
      if (!localIterator.hasNext())
        return;
      ez localez = (ez)((Map.Entry)localIterator.next()).getValue();
      if (localez.a(paramInt1, paramInt2, paramInt3, paramInt4))
        localez.a(paramf, this.k, this.m, this.i, this.j);
    }
  }
```

You'll notice that all 3 methods above (taken from the same class) have the same name = 'a'. Of course this doesn't cause a problem when running because they have different parameters. However in my obfuscated stack trace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.get(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:117)
at uk.co.ionage.ionage.co.a(Unknown Source)
at uk.co.ionage.ionage.co.g(Unknown Source)
at uk.co.ionage.ionage.n.b(Unknown Source)
at uk.co.ionage.ionage.n.a(Unknown Source)
at uk.co.ionage.ionage.co.a(Unknown Source)
at uk.co.ionage.ionage.co.a(Unknown Source)
at uk.co.ionage.ionage.Gameplay.a(Unknown Source)
at uk.co.ionage.ionage.cn.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is a problem. I don't know which 'a' method it refers to. When I use retrace.bat it lists all methods with the name 'a'.

Here is my proguard.config:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-dontwarn android.support.**
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with
#fields. Proguard removes such information by default, so configure it to keep
#all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.gameanalytics.android.** { *; }
##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson ----------
```

It's very typical except I've added a bit at the end to help support my use of JSON/GSON.

Can I add an option to force proguard to give every method a different name?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The stack trace has become ambiguous because the line numbers are missing. You can preserve them with these ProGuard options:

```
-renamesourcefileattribute MyApplication
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

See the ProGuard manual > ReTrace > [Usage](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/retrace/usage.html).

See the ProGuard manual > Examples > [Producing useful stack traces](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#stacktrace)

Alternatively, you could assign unique names:

```
-useuniqueclassmembernames
```

However. method names can be overloaded to start with, and ProGuard doesn't change that.

Side-note: recent versions of the Android SDK automatically apply the default part of your configuration if you set up project.properties properly:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've marked this correct because adding the line numbers has solved my issue. I did try -useuniqueclassmembernames but am I right in thinking this change makes all local variables unique, not methods? I still have many methods called 'a'.

Comment: With -useuniqueclassmembernames, field names and method names that are different in the original code will also be different in the processed code, across all classes. This means that you may still see methods named 'a', but there should be fewer of them.

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification :)